# Avoid push in a particular branch

Tags: git, github, gitlab, push

is it possible to avoid push into a particular branch?
I have  a branch, which exists only for test deploys on our dev server.
It should only be able to be pull from other branches.

Comment: were are you pushing to? GitHub or GitLab or somewhere else?

Comment: This would fall under branch security, which is typically controlled by your Git Repository hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain but I think there are options in GitHub which can prevent this from happening. Assuming I have understood you correctly; you only want people to be able to pull and not push to this branch, then you can activate merge requests.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/

Any pushes to the branch would need to be approved via the merge request.

Comment: On github you can protected branches, if you have the appropriate subscription.